# Escoder extensão .php através do arquivo .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Estou usando o seguinte código em um servidor web, da hostgator, mas não consigo esconder a extensão `.php`. Como resolver isso?

```htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Você está fazendo isso no localhost? usando qual servidor wamp?

Comment: Você verificou se o `rewrite_module` esta ativo?

Comment: Então, parece que esse código RewriteEngine on ativa, de acordo com um tutorial que li

Comment: Estou fazendo em um servidor web, da hostgator

Comment: [a resposta pra nao ter que mudar todas as paginas ou arquivos esta no link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248772/17590)

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\\.php [L]
```

Claro que isso não impedirá do usuário digitar diretamente na URL. `/arquivo.php`

Exemplo de uso.

Você tem uma página `http://foo.bar/home.php`, então poderá acessar como `http://foo.bar/home`

Comment: Funcionou!
Na verdade estava pensando que a função simplesmente escondia a extensão.
Tirei as extensões de alguns links que direcionam para as páginas e deu certo, não exibe mais a extensão, só que no site tem mais de 200 links para eliminar a extensão de cada um...