# .htaccess trocar extensões .php e .html automaticamente?

Tags: php, html, htaccess

Estou usando meu htaccess assim

```
# Hide .html or .php extension
## External Redirect 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC]

## ## Internal Redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php
```

> quando acesso **meusite.com.br/pasta/site/teste.php**  OK ele monta minha url assim ...............
> ( meusite.com.br/pasta/site/teste ) e fica sem a extensão , porem se eu acessar assim ...
>
> meusite.com.br/pasta/site/usuarios.php === Dá erro 404
>
> meusite.com.br/pasta/site/index.php  === Dá erro 404
>
> **pois ele monta essas 2 urls ai acima assim ...**
>
> meusite.com.br/index/
>
> meusite.com.br/usuarios/
>
> **Quando deveria montar normal assim .......**
>
> meusite.com.br/pasta/site/usuarios
>
> meusite.com.br/pasta/site/index

**Onde preciso mudar ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha sugestão é que faça a checagem verificando se o "arquivo" (sendo real ou "virtual") seja considerado apenas em URL após o slash (`/`), isto porque evitaria conflitos com arquivos com nomes diferentes (é um pouco dificil detalhar o problema agora), deve ser algo como:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redireciona
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC,L]

# Reescreve
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|)$ $1.php [L]
```

O `(.*)` pega o caminho e o `(/|)` é pra "ignorar" o `/`, isto vai ajudar acaso acesse a URL assim:

- `site.com/foo/bar/`

Que iria causar isto:

- `/pasta/public_html/foo/bar/.php`

E isto não existe, se entendi você quer que `/foo/bar` e `/foo/bar/` (urls de exemplo) acessem `/foo/bar.php`, o código acima deve resolver, agora **acaso não funcione**, tente assim (ps: não tive tempo de testar):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redireciona
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC,L]

# Reescreve
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/]+)(/|)$ $1$2.php [L]
```

Se você tiver algum formulário POST que envia para o `.php`, isso vai falhar:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC,L]
```

Pois vai conflitar o POST e o redirecionamento, o que você pode fazer é uma checagem, algo como:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redireciona
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(PUT|POST)$ [NC] #ignora o POST e PUT
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC,L]

# Reescreve
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|)$ $1.php [L]
```

Ainda sim o melhor é ajustar os seus FORMs, tirar o `.php`, assim:

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" method="post" action="validaacesso.php">
```

por

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" method="post" action="validaacesso">
```

Comment: OK tentei as duas formas apresentadas e esta agora com o problema do tópico com aquelas duas url só elas que não funcionam , e se eu sair do sistema e tentar logar novamente não encontra o usuario e senha . não loga tbm

Comment: Não se eu tirar o .htaccess da pasta ,  funciona tudo certinho ! Claro === mostrando a extensão dos arquivos .

Comment: ok, vc entrou no sistema normal OK ,  agora vou subir o htaccess que me orientou e vc  tente acessar por exemplo  usuarios , painel principal no menu   e saia e tente fazer login novamente ,   ok,  estou subindo aqui o htaccess

Comment: ok, pode testar já

Comment: Entendi,  mas esse htaccess não deveria retirar as extenções automaticamente  ?

Comment: é o que perguntei no post , se ha alguma forma de o htaccess remover extenções dos arquivos automaticamente sem eu ter que refazer todo o meu script

Comment: ok, e por exemplo por que não acessa usuarios  nem o painel principal via menu lateral, mas os outros acessam normalmente

Comment: ok, mas usuarios e menu principal === no menu lateral não são forms, são paginas como as outras do menu lateral , as outras acessam essas ai não

Comment: ué tenho que editar todos os links então

Comment: Remova por favor os comentarios onde tem links !  do meu sistema aqui ,

Comment: Mas resumindo === Não existe um htaccess que esconda automaticamente as extensões então ?

Comment: @PauloMaia pra um melhor funcionamento sim, afinal url são caminhos virtuais, se estivesse usando um Framework como Laravel as urls seria escritas via rotas e nem existiria `.php`. Como eu disse todas urls funcionam aqui, menos as páginas com POST porque obviamente elas conflitam, pois vc esta afetando o comportamento, entenda que redirecionamentos não irão fazer mágica pra ti, o ideal de ter algo que remove a extensão (como já disse urls são tudo "virtuais") é pra garantir não ter páginas duplicadas. O problema é que você não entende HTTP e de servidores para entender o conceito.

Comment: @PauloMaia As coisas funciona via **Requisição** e **Resposta** e URLs não acessam "arquivos diretamente", o que é feito ali é um mapeamento para assimilar algo como `c:/wamp/htdcos/foo.php` para algo como `http://localhost/foo.php`. Isso é o básico do que é HTTP.

Comment: A checagem lá que vc orientou na sua resposta,  dá ERRO 500 para tudo agora

Comment: essa aqui assim = https://pastebin.com/MJcfmiUP  ERRO 500 para tudo ...

Comment: @PauloMaia não sei dizer o que houve, tenta troca `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(PUT|POST)$` por `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} (PUT|POST)`

Comment: @PauloMaia cara nao precisa mandar 2 comentário, eu já li o primeiro :/ ... então troca por isto `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(PUT|POST)$ [NC]`, é que faltava a flag `NC`

Comment: ok,  acessa ai pra vc ver   usuarios e painel principal nada ainda https://pastebin.com/n6FSyDeN

Comment: @PauloMaia pra esta normal http://rpmon.com.br/SiteSys/controle/usuarios veja um print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmyp1.png

Comment: @PauloMaia sim, todos links eu cliquei pelo menu lateral, naveguei em todas páginas possiveis clicando em tudo, funcionou normalmente pra mim.

Comment: Estranho aqui para mim rpmon.com.br/SiteSys/controle/usuarios  ERRO 404

Comment: @PauloMaia aperta Ctrl+F5 (ou apenas F5 duas vezes).

Comment: o login logou normal , corrigiu o erro com sua verificação aqui ta ok o login

Comment: Entendi -  pode ser sim estava fazendo testes aqui anteriormente .....  vou limpar o cache pois o index ja esta normal  = pelo menu painel principal 
=== vc tentou alterar em parametros , da mensagem ai acima , que acho que esta perdendo o encoding

Comment: ok, limpei o cache e o usuario ta normal agora  !

Comment: @PauloMaia blz, então acho que agora está tudo ok.

Comment: tente tbm alterar em parametros o campo corpo do e-mail e de um salvar ele salva mas parece que perde o UTF encoding na mensagem !

Comment: @PauloMaia isso de UTF é muito amplo, pode ser qualquer coisa, siga o passo a passo disso que deve ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: Vc chegou a testar na pagina lá,  e viu como mostra a mensagem de SUCESSO  ? Já vi htaccess que adiciona utf  nas paginas automaticamente , vc conhece essa linha  ?

Comment: @PauloMaia ah, entendi, ***não tem nada haver*** com UTF, o problema é a querystring que esta sendo reformatada, vou tentar ajustar e te aviso.

Comment: Ajustar onde ?   no htaccess  ,  dai vc poe lá no pastebiin ?

Comment: @PauloMaia eu (Guilherme Nascimento) vou *"tentar"* ajustar, não sei se é o .htaccess, pode ser o teu script, pode ser qualquer coisa, não tem como saber

Comment: OK, Aguardo !   pois antes do htaccess não ficava assim a mensagem cheia de caracteres estranhos .

Comment: @PauloMaia É, mas não tem haver com UTF, o problema é que o escape de URL esta sendo causado duas vezes, esses caracteres com `%` indica URL-Encoded, vou "tentar" descobrir, mas como eu já disse, pode ser problema no teu `.php`, independente se antes funcionava ou não, pois tem problemas que só ocorrem em cenários especificos e não falham em outros por simples "sorte".

Comment: Entendi Companheiro !  Aguardo você ...

Comment: Para esconder html e php   fica assim o htaccess ? https://pastebin.com/xL15Nh7c

Comment: Retire os comentarios que contem url para o sistema.

Comment: esta por ai, não estou conseguindo ocultar php e html no mesmo htaccess

Comment: E acrescentar a / no final das url

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67698/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-htaccess-trocar-extensoes-php-e)

Answer (score 3):

Eu faria assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Sua definições aqui

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php
```

Essa expressão regular de `RewriteRule` diz para que qualquer coisa aponte para `.php` caso não tenha a extensão, porém a uri atual requirida não deve ser uma arquivo ou pasta existente no servidor (definições de `RewriteCond`).

Comment: Em qual das linhas amigo ?

Comment: Corrigi o código. Substitua o trecho abaixo de `##Internal Redirect`

Comment: OK, substitui no trecho ##Internal Redirect porem agora não roda nenhuma. Diz ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS  esta pagina não esta funcionando , para todas agora !

Comment: Não funcionou por que ?

Comment: @PauloMaia teria como você conferir no log do Apache? Pois simplesmente saber que não funcionou não ajuda muito na identificação do problema.

Comment: @PauloMaia vc deve ter misturado dois Rewrites, é bem provavel que teu .htaccess tenha mais coisas, poste no http://pastebin.com ele completo e manda o link aqui pro Wallace analisar.

Comment: @PauloMaia troque a linha por isto `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]`

Comment: ele não esta gerando error.log na pasta

Comment: Não existe outro .htaccess na pasta /site/ === que é onde estão todos os arquivos.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento  troquei a linha e na mesma nenhuma pagina agora acessa !

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento === https://pastebin.com/vZzyLmBF

Comment: @PauloMaia por isso esta dando problema, vc misturou o código do Wallace com o seu, isso não faz sentido algum de se fazer.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento Mudei e agora não retira as extenções .php não  === https://pastebin.com/HQqsRyCN

Comment: @PauloMaia isso ae não tem nada haver com o código do Wallace, cadê o `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento === Mesma coisa não retira as extensões não 
https://pastebin.com/fLNX8aWy

Comment: @PauloMaia Não tenho como testar, mas faça assim que deve funcionar: https://pastebin.com/6uaj80dJ (me avisa)

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento === https://pastebin.com/6uaj80dJ === OK  esta agora com o problema do tópico  com aquelas duas url só elas que não funcionam , e se eu sair do sistema e tentar logar novamente não encontra o usuario e senha .  não loga tbm